# Count daily items

Tags: mysql

I'm using following command to get daily items.
Column date is unix timestamp.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(date) as datetime, COUNT(id) AS total 
FROM items 
WHERE cat_id = 3 
GROUP BY datetime 
HAVING datetime BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND NOW()
```

The result is:

### datetime        |     total

2019-01-11 09:39:12   |       1

2019-01-11 09:44:35  |       1

2019-01-11 09:47:55  |       1

2019-01-15 14:33:00  |       1

2019-01-15 14:34:31  |       1

2019-01-17 14:39:26  |       1

Actually i'm looking for second result:

### datetime        |     total

2019-01-11 09:39:12  |       3

2019-01-15 14:33:00  |       2

2019-01-17 14:39:26  |       1

Comment: Have you tried `GROUP BY DATE(datetime)`?

Comment: Oh my god that is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `GROUP BY` to `GROUP BY DATE(datetime)`

Answer (score 1):

You should group by DATE instead of DATE with TIME

```
SELECT  
  DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) AS `datetime`,
  COUNT(`id`) AS `total`
FROM `items`
WHERE `cat_id` = 3
GROUP BY DATE(datetime)
HAVING datetime BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01') AND NOW()
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but Kay Nelson has answered into comments and he deserve :)